# How to fix "This template attempted to load a component assembly 'LigerShark.Templates'"

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2013, assembly-loading

I'm trying to create a new C# Application based on a template model.
This template uses Ligershark (side-waffle).
On creating, i got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpslS.jpg)

What i tried :

I downloaded the project on github (https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle),
built the solution and added Ligershark.Templates.dll to the GAC (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool).

But it does nothing.

I visited several questions about the same kind of error, but the solutions proposed are not working for me..

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Resolved installing https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SideWaffleTemplatePack